# Does Ubuntu software center needs update ....?

Tags: updates, software-center

I'm the newest Ubuntu user, so have a little mercy on me ... :)

I'm trying to install g++ 4.7, the version I have is 4.6.
I looked for it in the Ubuntu software center and didn't find it so I ended up getting it from the command line.

(sorry of the long intro ... )

do I need to update Ubuntu software center some how so it can find new software releases...?

if so how do I do that, if not, then why it couldn't find the new version of g++ ?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, and wellcome. Software in the repositories is usually not the latest version - this is the way Ubuntu works. If you need the latest and greatest, Ubuntu is probably not the best choice. Try Arch Linux instead.

Comment: I was watching a tutorial video and the guy typed in the search box, g++-4.7 and he got a result back, from the software center.
I didn't when I tried it my self, why is that ?

Comment: Depends on the version of Ubuntu you have. Apparently [13.04 has g++ 4.7.3 and 13.10 has 4.8.1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&searchon=names&keywords=g%2B%2B). Switch to either of these and you are good to go.